If $p_t(x,y)>0 $ for some $t$, then $p_t(x,y) >0 $ for all $t\geq 0 $.
Suppose one has given a transition function $p_t(x,y)$ on a countable state space $E$, and continuous time $t \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0 }$ i.e.

the Chapman Kolmogorov equation holds
\begin{equation} p_{t+s}(x,y) = \sum_{z \in E} p_t(x,z)p_s(z,y) \end{equation}
its stochastic, i.e. $\sum_{z \in E} p(x,z) = 1$
continuous at $0$, i.e. $\lim_{t -> 0^+} p_t(x,x) = 1 $

I want to prove the claim that for any fixed pair $x,y \in E$ it holds
\begin{equation}  \exists s>0: p_s(x,y) > 0  \Leftrightarrow \forall s>0 : p_s(x,y) > 0  \end{equation}
Using continuity and the Chapman Kolmogorov equations, its straightforward to show that $p_t(x,y) \geq p_{t-s}(x,x) p_s(x,y) $ so that together with $p_t(x,x) > 0, \forall t$, the statement is can be proven for $t>s$. But I am struggling to show that if $\exists s : p_s(x,y)>0 \Rightarrow \forall 0< t< s: p_t(x,y) > 0 $. So far, I have seen only proofs that use the embedded Markov chain associated to the Markov process, but I would like to use only the above properties of $p_t(x,y)$.

Could you provide some references for the proofs using embedded markov chains?

It should be contained in Liggett: Continuous Time Markov Processes.

Since p_t(·,·) is a transition function, it satisfies p_t(x,x) > 0 for all t > 0. Assume x  ̸= y and p_t(x,y) > 0 for some t > 0. Then, the embedded discrete-time Markov chain has a positive probability to go from x to y in finitely many steps. Since the waiting times between jumps are exponentially distributed, the continuous-time chain satisfies p_t(x, y) = P_x(X_t = y) > 0 for any t > 0.

Sorry but this reasoning is not understandable, plus if it makes sense then you have simplified this deep result a lot so I doubt the validity of your argument. Perhaps you may want to post it as a detailed answer?

sure but I suggest rather, that you open a new question for that, and then I can submit a more thorough answer there

It's pointless to open a new thread to ask for the exact same question as you posted here. Also, this is a community and not a competition, so if you want to compete to get points from posting your answer (which I doubt that it's not true), then it goes against the spirit here. Plus, I can upvote your answer in this post too. If you are not eager to justify your reasoning, then it's ok, I still don't believe it and tell myself that such a proof doesn't exist. But if your reasoning is true, your answer will help future readers (and me) learn something new, which is very good for this community!

ok fair, I misremembered how exactly I asked the question , I thought I made it clear that I specifically didn't want the embedded MC proof, but now I see that it still makes sense to post the embedded -proof.

This is essentially an assertion due to P. Lévy (under your conditions 1.-3.): For distinct states $x$ and $y$, either $p_t(x,y)=0$ for all $t>0$ or $p_t(x,y)>0$ for all $t>0$. This is a rather deep result. The first proof is due to D.G. Austin; a simplified exposition of Austin's proof appears on pp. 149-151 in K.L. Chung's book Markov Chains with Stationary Transition Probabilities.

I see so either way (e.g. using the embedded chain) one has to do quite a lot of work ... thanks !

For completeness sake, here are some details for the proof using the embedded chain: Suppose $p_s(x,y)>0 $ for some $s >0 $. Then using the construction from Liggett, where $(Z_n)_n$ is the embedded chain:
\begin{equation}
0< p_s(x,y) = P(Z_{N_s} = y, N_s < \infty | Z_0 =  x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty P(Z_k = y, N_s = k | Z_0 = x) \leq \sum_{k=1}^\infty P(Z_k = y|Z_0= x) 
\end{equation}
Hence there is some $k\geq 1$ such that $P(Z_k = y|Z_0 = x) >0 $. In particular there are $x_0 = x, x_1, \dots, x_k = y$ such that
\begin{equation}
P(Z_k = x_k | Z_{k-1} = x_{k-1}) \cdot \dots \cdot P(Z_1 = x_1 | Z_0 = x_0) > 0 
\end{equation}
Now let $t>0$ arbitrary. Compute now
\begin{equation}
p_t(x,y) = P(Z_{N_t} = y, N_t < \infty | Z_0 = x) \geq P(Z_k = y, N_t = y| Z_0 = x) 
 \geq P(Z_k = x_k, \dots, Z_1 = x_1, N_t = y | Z_0 = x) = P(Z_k = x_k, \dots, Z_1 = x_1, Z_0 = x_0, N_t = k)/P(Z_0 = x) 
\end{equation}
Now notice that with $\tau_i$ the $i$-th holding times
\begin{equation}
\{N_t = k\} = \{ \tau_0 + \dots + \tau_{k-1} < s \leq \tau_0 + \dots + \tau_k \}
\end{equation}
Now conditioned on the path $x_0 \to x_1 \dots \to x_k$ we have that the holding times are independent (also independent of the embedded chain) and exponentially $\tau_i |\{  X_i = x_i \}  =: T_i  \sim \exp(-q(x_i, x_i)) $ distributed (note that wlog the $x_i$ are not absorbing as otherwise one couldn't reach $x_k$; also assume that all the states are not instantaneous, so that the the Q matrix is in $Q \in \mathbb{R}^{E \times E} $ and thus the construction from Liggett works). Hence using $c(x_i) := -q(x_i, x_i)$ we get
\begin{equation}
P(Z_k = x_k, \dots, Z_0 = x_0, N_t = k) = P(Z_k = x_k, \dots, Z_0= x_0) P(T_0 + \dots + T_{k-1} < s \leq T_0 + \dots + T_{k}) 
\end{equation}
The factor on the right is now $>0$ since by the elementary Markov property
\begin{equation}
P(Z_k = x_k, \dots, Z_0 = x_0) = P(Z_k = x_k | Z_{k-1} = x_{k-1}) \dots P(Z_1 = x_1 | Z_0 = x_0) P(Z_0 = x_0)  > 0 
\end{equation}
and $P(T_0 + \dots + T_{k-1} < s \leq T_0 + \dots + T_k) > 0 $ as $T_k \sim \exp(-q(y,y))$. Hence comparison with above yields $p_t(x,y) >0 $.

Thanks for your effort, there are a few problems that I can see. Usually, we begin with transition functions $(p_t(\cdot,\cdot)){t\geq 0}$ and then we can define a process on some prob space such that $P(X_t =y | X_s) = p{t-s}(X_s,y)$ a.s. and the meaning of $P(X_t =y | X_s = x)$ is just $p_{t-s}(x,y)$, but $P(Z_k=y|Z_0 =x)$ not well defined in your answer so you cannot say there are $x_0=x,....,x_k=y$ s.t $P(...)P(....)>0$. Next, how do you know $P(Z_0 =x) >0$ (to divide it)? Next, you assume all states are not instantaneous, that's an additional assumption on transition functions!

This is still far from a correct proof, but I value your effort so still (+1).

yeah, its not self contained in the sense that I am using the approach starting from a well defined $Q$ matrix, as outlined in Liggett (there he constructs the probability space and the embedded chain from scratch etc. for example the initial distribution there is chosen precisely such that P(Z_0 =x)> 0 for any $x \in E$)

Okay, the probability space stuff can be fixed easily. But to talk about $Q$ matrix, you have to assume more for transition functions and usually this is much more easier to work with. For example, if I am given a $Q$ such that the operator norm $|Q| <+\infty $ then the transition matrix arising from $Q$ can be written $P_t = e^{tQ}$ and from this, you immediately get $p_t(x,y)>0$ for any $t\geq 0$ iff $x \rightarrow y$ in the transition graph of $Q$.

yeah the prove above works only for transition functions, whose $Q$ matrix lies in $R^{E\times E}$. but I guess since processes like the linear birth and death chain have in general no finite operator norm, the above is still useful (e.g. the lecture notes that I learned it from only ever considered processes coming from $Q$ matrices)
